# Compatibility of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel 14.0.0.0 with MS Office 2019

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I have a windows form application build using Visual Studio 2012. Application is running on Windows server 2008 R2 where MS Office 2010 is installed.

Currently, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll - 14.0.0.0 has been used in application to open the excel files using MS Office 2010.

Application is running perfectly at client end. Now my client has requested to upgrade the version of Microsoft Office 2010 to Microsoft Office 2019.

1. Will Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll - 14.0.0.0 library support Microsoft Office 2019?
2. Will the format of my Excel reports generating currently remain same when office version will be upgraded?

Comment: I do not think any upgrading is needed for the application, because *most* Office products are `backwards compatible`. So, the current created Excel files should also load in Office 2019. REMEMBER: Only use functionality that was available in the version of 'Microsoft.Interop….' that you are using...

Comment: You can't get a warranty here, recent versions have had breaking changes.  Inevitable for an object model that is 21 years old.  Consider how you are going to support your users if it *does* fail and you'll almost inevitably will do the right thing.